# Different slope in 'regression' between ggplot (by suing geom_smooth(method = "lm") , and lm -function

Tags: r

I am using a data-set (Panel).

With this data-set I conduct the following:

1)

```
ols <-lm(CapNormChange ~ Policychanges, data=Panel) summary(ols) 

plot(Panel$CapNormChange, Panel$Policychanges, 
      pch=19, xlab="CapNormChange", ylab="Policychanges") 
abline(lm(Panel$CapNormChange~Panel$Policychanges),lwd=3, col="blue")
```

and 2)

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = Panel, mapping = aes(x = CapNormChange, y = Policychanges)) 
p2 + geom_point(alpha=0.3) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=F, color="orange")
```

I thought that the slopes of the lines of germ-smooth and and abline of the first plot are the same, and also correspond to the parameter of the dependent variable (Policychanges) in the OLS regression.

However, this is not the case ! Instead the ggplot, has a higher intercept (I tested it for different dataset). I really don't understand this, could please somebody give some advice?

Comment: Sorry, for the horrible code parts...

Comment: Is that data set public, or can you show the same problem with some public data or something created by code?

Comment: Hi Spacedman, it is private data... I will try to change the x and y as suggested by Roland first, before trying with public data, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In 1) you use `CapNormChange` as y-variable and `Policychanges` as x-variable. It's always `y ~ x`. This doesn't match what you do in the `plot` command. In 2) you do it the other way around.

OLS regression assumes that only y-values have associated errors. Thus, swapping x and y changes the fit. If you want the same results from both, you'd need [orthogonal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares#Geometrical_interpretation).

Comment: I will swap x and y (and try again) - I thought I got it right. thank you a lot !!!

Comment: Ok, it works now. I think I got confused because ggplot puts the aches the other way round (?!)

Comment: I use know the command    
p2 + geom_point(alpha=0.3) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=F, color="orange")+coord_flip().  - so that I get the same graph as with the plot and to be consistent. Thanks again.